# How to see the mesh with subdivisions in wireframe mode in blender 2.83?

Tags: subdivision-surface, wireframe

Hi I can't see how to see the mesh with all subdivisions in blender 2.83. Does anyone know how it can be activated? in past versions I think it was by default

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**Turn off Optimal Display**

[image]

Came across this as well, found that switching the subsurf modifiers optimal display property has the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked